# Como hacer para que el programa no haga nada en un condicional

Tags: java, eclipse, java-swing

Puede que suene rara mi pregunta, pero estoy armando un videojuego fácil en Java, lo estoy trabajando con eclipse las interfaces gráficas, y hay una parte en que tengo lo siguiente: Tengo un JTable donde en cada fila tengo almacenado datos de un personaje y un boton de agregar, donde la idea es que cada vez que seleccione al personaje, el boton agregar lo añada a otra Jtable, y necesito que esta última tabla tenga un máximo de 25 filas, y para eso le puse un if else, donde if es el tamaño si es menor a 25 que lo añade, pero en else no se que poner para que si el tamaño es igual o mayor a 25 no haga nada, pues por regla del juego, no debe superar los 25 personajes.

Comment: Podrias mostrar el codigo que usas para eso? no entiendo donde esta el problema. solo no haces nada o muestras un mensaje que diga que llegaste al maximo...

Comment: No es obligatorio poner siempre el **else** en los condicionales. Pero si quieres ponerlo cuando tiene nada que hacer, puedes hacerlo sin poner código, aunque la mayoría de IDEs te dan una alerta de que el **else** no realiza ninguna operación (supongo que por eso lo dices).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner simplemente

```
if(condicion){

}
```

El else no es obligatorio, es mas se maneja como que fuera otro tipo de condicional por isa decirlo, entonces puedes tener tu if sin el else, dado que tu else no hace nada.